# Erro ao injetar source do script do googlemaps via método

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google

Gostaria que o [**geocomplete**](https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) não desse erro, porém, para funcionar, ele depende da API do google maps.
Removi do cabeçalho o seguinte script e passei via método:

```
 <script id="id_script" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=nome-cliente&v=3.21&language=pt-br&libraries=places&components=country:Brasil"></script>
 //(1) código removido
```

Onde estava e funcionava assim:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" id="jquery"></script>
 <script src="/js/jquery.geocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 //1. antes ele estava aqui ----
  <script id="id_script" src="default.js"></script>
</head>
```

O método que criei faz o mesmo que o script (1) que era carregado no head:

```
function googleMapsScriptById(client, id) {
    var url_maps = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?'+client+'v=3.21&language=pt-br&libraries=places&components=country:Brasil';

    (function () {
        var gmaps = document.createElement('script');
        gmaps.type = 'text/javascript';
        gmaps.async = true;
        gmaps.src = url_maps;
        var ref = document.getElementById(id);
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(gmaps, ref);
    })();
}

googleMapsScriptById('client=nome-cliente&','id_script');
```

Só que agora estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem, de erro do geocomplete, que antes de fazer esta alteração, não apresentava:

> jquery.geocomplete.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

O que pode ser, existe alguma maneira de ajustar a sincronia entre os dois?

**Minhas conclusões:**

Mesmo que eu inverta, a ordem de carregamento:

```
<head>
<script id="antes_desse"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" id="jquery"></script>
 <script src="/js/jquery.geocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script id="id_script" src="default.js"></script>
</head>
```

Exemplo:

```
googleMapsScriptById('client=nome-cliente&','antes_desse');
```

Ainda persiste o erro, pois o que entendo é que as bibliotecas no head são pré-carregadas antes de executar o método: `googleMapsScriptById();`, e neste caso, como as demais já estão na head, e esta do google, ainda não foi carregada, sua dependências simplesmente apresentam erro.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de fazer isso, como fazemos com uso de Promise?

Answer (score 2):

Ivan,

A API Javascript do Google Maps está sendo carregada antes da API do Geocomplete, aonde o mesmo necessita da API do Google.

Na função que você criou para inserir a API do Google Maps, insira depois o Geocomplete.

**UPDATE**: O atributo "*async*" não irá bloquear o carregamento dos outros scripts, caso você o remova, o carregamento poderá ser mais lento, porém a API do Google Maps já estará carregada.

Mais informações aqui: [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

Comment: Não entendi? 
Depois o geocomplete ou depois do geocomplete?

Comment: Depois o Geocomplete. Como ele necessita do Google Maps, você tem que ter a certeza de que a API do mapa está 100% carregada antes de carregar o Geocomplete. Nos meus projetos eu utilizo via _tag_ no HTML mesmo, porém sem o _async_.

Comment: Então, mas eu teitei também passando a id do script do jquery, acima, para que, justamente, ele criasse a tag, antes do geocomplete... e mesmo assim, o erro persiste. Acredito que o método de inserção está sendo carregado após o carregamento do geocomplete. Por isso o erro. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de fazer meu método ser mais rápido que tudo isso?

Comment: Tente colocar os scripts nessa ordem:
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=nome-cliente&v=3.21&language=pt-br&libraries=places&components=country:Brasil"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" id="jquery"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.geocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script id="id_script" src="default.js"></script>`.

Dessa forma o Google Maps será carregado primeiro, depois o jQuery, depois o Geocomplete e por último o "default.js".

Comment: Então, mesmo que a inserção seja nesta ordem, está dando erro, conforme eu disse acima.

Comment: A única solução que consigo pensar é em passar todas as dependências através do método, a menos que exista uma solução melhor ou mais simples, pois não queria mexer nessas outras, talvez algo que faça meu método se tornar sincronizado.

Comment: Que estranho, seguindo a ordem que te passei, era para funcionar. Veja na página de exemplo do plugin.

Exemplo: 
[HTML](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/simple.html. 

Código: (view-source:http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/simple.html).

Caso realmente não funcione, tente então carregar as dependências através do método que você criou mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47330/discussion-between-douglas-garrido-and-ivan-ferrer).